# Public shared function and cookies or sessions asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I have implement a Public shared function in my aspx.vb page (not in class or web service) to use it with javascript but I had problem with creating a cookies and sessions

How can I create cookies or sessions in that shared function? any ideia!

Thank you all.

Comment: Please provide some code. You should also look at ASP.NET page life cycle event. Which I believe will certainly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<WebMethod> _ Public Shared Sub Test(text As String)
Dim ctx As HttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current
ctx.Session("Test") = text
ctx.Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Value = text
```

End Sub